# How do I customize the length of the token generated in :token_authenticatable in devise - Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

My token generated seems to be about 20 characters, how do I change the length to something else ?

I checked the `devise.rb` file and tried both:

```
config.token_authentication_key = :access_key    
config.token_authenticatable.length = 40
```

produced this error:

```
config/initializers/devise.rb:110:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `token_authenticatable' for Devise:Module (NoMethodError)
```

and

```
config.token_authentication_key = :access_key
config.token_authentication_key.length = 40
```

produced this error:

```
/config/initializers/devise.rb:110:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `length=' for :access_key:Symbol (NoMethodError)
```

and both gave me errors when I tried to run the console.

Is there anyway to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devise does not provide a functionality to set the length of this token. You would have to override the `generate_token` method on your model to change the outcome of this token.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved changing the `reset_token_password` length overriding the `friendly_token` method. For example:

`module Devise
  def self.friendly_token(_length = 20)
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(5).tr('lIO0', 'sxyz')
  end
end`

(Remember that the tokens are hashed in the db so even though you successfully set a shorter code if you do `user.reset_password_token` you will see a long code which is the hashed token, not the real one.)