# Can I increase the size of the auth tokens used in devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Is it possible to increase the size of the authentication tokens used by devise. Currently they generate tokens of length 20 characters. I want 64 character tokens.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534836/how-do-i-customize-the-length-of-the-token-generated-in-token-authenticatable-i?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for increase the size of the auth tokens you have to override the `generate_token` method on your model. `generate_token` is devise method that you have to override with your method that you write in your model.

see in devise - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb